# Host ASPX file next to WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I don't know if this is even possible, but let's give it a try:

I'm having a WCF Service, Self Hosted. Next to this service, I would like to have an ASPX file that my load balancer can check if this service is still running properly (amongst other database checks) which is going to be deployed on the same location as my WCF service.

So I added a ASPX file, changed the namespaces and stuff.

Then, after clean/rebuild, I started the service, and browsed to the aspx page: It gves me a parser error: `Could not load type "<<namespace>>.Global"`

So I added a Global.asax file, retried, same error

I created these two file (aspx and asax) in a seperate WebApplication where they work fine.

I also read somewhere that for this technique, I would have to have the following in my app.config:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

But this doesn't make any difference (for this specific problem)

ANy clue on this? I don't want to have the ASPX file being placed anywhere on a virtual directory.

Or is there an alternative way to get what I want? (maybe with an ashx) ??

Comment: Are you adding the dll of the application??

Comment: Why not just expose diagnostic methods from the service?

Answer (score 0):

The application is trying to access the dll that it seems you are not adding.
you should add a bin folder and inside it add the dll of your application.

Comment: The output path is set to bin\debug (for the service). Inside this path al my files are built. Also, in the parent folder (bin) i copied all the files for test, and this doesn't make a difference.